# Unable to read variable from netCDF file

Tags: python, variables, multidimensional-array, netcdf

I'm trying to read a specific variable from a netCDF file but have been unable to do so. the variable is data type "int16" and has five dimensions integrated into it (e.g. latitude, longitude, time, elevation, etc.). So far, here is what I've tried and, consequently, here are the errors I've received.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
x = nc.Dataset('file.nc')
lat = x.variables('lat')
print(lat)
shape = x.variables('shape')
```

The error reads:

```
"Attribute Error: netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in             
netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset._getattr_()
netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset._getncattr_()
netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset._get_att_()
netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset._ensure_nc_success_()
Attribute Error: NetCDF: Attribute not found.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The code in your post reads `x.variables`, the one in the image reads `x.variable`. Which is it? Might that be the issue?

Comment: AMC, thank you! Yes, this dealt with the actual reading-the-variable issue. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Some typo's above.  Try this:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
x = nc.Dataset('file.nc')
lat = x.variables['lat']
print(lat)
shape = x.variables['lat'].shape
# or 
shape = lat.shape
print(shape)
```

Comment: Thank you, Eric!